# Are the sets of solutions of two polynomials equal?

Tags: polynomials

my cousin started studying mathematics and asked me something a few days ago and I was not able to answer his question. I am feeling kind of stupid, because the problem itself seems to be ridicolously easy.

So, look at the two sets defined by:
\begin{align*}
&A:=\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \vert x^2 - 6x + 5 = 0 \right\}
\\
&B:=\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \vert x-2+\sqrt{2x-1} = 0 \right\}
\end{align*}
The question is, are these two sets equal?
Using the known formula for polynomials with grade $2$, we get:
\begin{align*}
A = \left\{ 1, 5 \right\}
\end{align*}
The trick is and thats where it starts to get confusing, look at the following equivalences:
\begin{align*}
&x-2 + \sqrt{2x -1} = 0 
\\
\Leftrightarrow 
&\left( x-2 \right)^2 = 2x-1
\\
\Leftrightarrow
&x^2-4x+4 = 2x-1
\\
\Leftrightarrow
&x^2 - 6x +5 = 0
\end{align*}
BUT, although after changing the term in $B$, we see that $5$ is no element in $B$, because $5-2 + \sqrt{10 -1} = 3 + 3 = 6$.
The only explanation I have is that there is something wrong in the equivalences. I am feeling kind of dumb, I think its pretty obvious.

Comment: Your first equivalence is only correct if $2 - x$ is positive.

Comment: $2-x$ or $x-2$?

Comment: The first equivalence is wrong. $x=y\implies x^n=y^n$, but the reverse doesn't hold.

Comment: $a = b \implies a^2 = b^2$ but $a^2 = b^2 \not \implies a = b$ so that is *not* an if and only iff statement in your first line.

Comment: oh my gosh, yeah thank you guys! now I feel really dumb!

Comment: You wrote $x - 2 + \sqrt{2x - 1} = 0 \iff (x-2)^2 = 2x -1$.  That is not true.   $x - 2 + \sqrt{2x - 1} = 0 \implies (x-2)^2 = 2x -1$ but not the other way. Instead do  $x - 2 + \sqrt{2x - 1} = 0 \iff (x-2)^2 = 2x -1; x\le 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction:

$\begin{align*}
&x-2 + \sqrt{2x -1} = 0 
\\
\Leftrightarrow 
&2-x =  \sqrt{2x -1} 
\\
\Leftrightarrow 
&\left( x-2 \right)^2 = 2x-1;2-x \ge 0
\\
\Leftrightarrow
&x^2-4x+4 = 2x-1; x\le 2
\\
\Leftrightarrow
&x^2 - 6x +5 = 0;x \le 2
\\
\Leftrightarrow
&x \in \{1,5\}; x\le 2
\\
\Leftrightarrow
&x = 1
\end{align*}$

Altough stylistically $x = 1 \iff x \in\{1,5\};x\le 2\iff x^2 -6x +5 = 0; x \le 2$, although true and correct, is *REALLY* weird to write.